# how to get the props result after calling another props function (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I have error for the following scenario:
Whenever I type a word in the input box,  and without triggering the `onBlur` function, I then click on the button. The code will then execute `_continue` function and then call `verify` function at `B.tsx`.

After I have finished running the verify function at `B.tsx`, the code haven't get the result for the following parameters (`this.props.validationSucceed and this.props.noEror`).

I would like to retrieve the correct result in the _continue function. I have tried debugging it in chrome developer tools, the code doesn't execute `this._nextSection` function because it does not get the result from `props.validationSuccedd` and `props.noError` yet.

(Note: If after I trigger the blur function for the input box, and then click on the button, the code does get the props result for the parameter (`this.props.validationSucceed` and `this.props.noEror`).)

A.tsx

```
_continue(){
  this.props.verify();
  if(this.props.validationSucceed && !this.props.noError){
     this._nextSection();
  }
}

verifyInformation(){
  this.props.verify();
}
render(){
   <input onBlur={this.props.verifyInformation}>
   <button type="button" className={button} 
      onClick={() => this._continue(1)}>Next</button>
}
```

B.tsx

```
render(){
  return(
      <component verify={this.state.verify} validationSucceed={this.state.validationSucceed} noError={this.state.noError}>
  )
}
constructor(props){
       super(props);
}
verify(){ 
    if(!data.error) {
        this.setState({validationSucceed: true, noError: false});
        this.otherFunction()
    } else {
        this.setState({validationSucceed: false, noError: true });
    }
}
```

Comment: You may try replacing `verify={this.state.verify}` to `verify={this.state.verify.bind(this)}` Will that make a difference?